# geofirestore not returning individual document data

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, geofirestore

We are using the [geofirestore npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geofirestore#documentation) to get nearby documents.

This is the Cloud Function we are using to get these documents.

```
exports.getNearbyOffers = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const offers = GeoFirestore.collection('restaurants');

    const center : GeoPoint = new admin.firestore.GeoPoint(data["sourceLat"], data["sourceLng"]);

    const query = offers.near({center: center, radius: 100,});

    return query.get().then((value) => {
        console.log(value.docs);
        return value.docs;
    }).catch((err: any) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

The output on the client-side is:

```
[{data: {}, distance: 0, exists: true, id: LdaLz30gv16Gv68Xw92i}, {data: {}, distance: 0, exists: true, id: Ux1Et5afklvZC4IKEkJy}, {data: {}, distance: 0, exists: true, id: h4kdFZpsn1UwPpTvPMxC}, {data: {}, distance: 0, exists: true, id: oqWfc41cfiWAcnvufVFd}, {data: {}, distance: 0, exists: true, id: pH0qW0V9rY43zvgkPQm8}]
```

The query is returning the correct document IDs.  However, the data of these documents is empty, but, in the Firestore console, each corresponding document has many fields with data (name, rating, address, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's expected because you are getting only the snapshot. you need to run the data() function on each doc to get their data:

```
query.get().then((value) => {
// All GeoDocument returned by GeoQuery, like the GeoDocument added above
  for (const doc of value.docs) {
    console.log(doc.data());
  }
```

Comment: This isn't clear in the documentation. Different sources say .getData() and just the .data field, but this is the correct answer.

Comment: geofirestore is just a wrapper around firestore and what applies on firestore applies on geofirestore and in this case it's the data() function. check this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document)